# Model as a group that can add other User models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I am having trouble trying to achieve the following, mostly in the controller part:

I have a User model and a Firm model. 
A User can create a Firm, this will mean that this user will be the firm owner. Additionally, this user can add other users to join the firm.

So far, my Models are as follows:

```
class Firm< ActiveRecord::Base        
    has_many :users, dependent: :destroy    
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...         
  belongs_to :bufete  
end
```

Here is my create action in my firms controller:

```
def create
       @bufete = Bufete.create(bufete_params)
       @user = current_user
       @bufete.users.create(@user)     # Mark that this user belongs to a bufete
       @user.owner = true               # Mark this user as the owner of the Bufete

        respond_to do |format|
            if @bufete.save && @user.save
                format.html { redirect_to @bufete, :flash => { :success => 'Tu bufete ha sido creado exitosamente.' } }
                format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bufete }
            else
                format.html { render 'new', :flash => { :danger => 'Hubo un error al tratar de crear tu bufete. 
                Porfavor asegurese de que el correo electronico es una direccion valida' } }
                format.json { render json: @bufete.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end 
    end
```

Schema.rb file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150730061404) do

  create_table "bufetes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "telephone"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "code"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.boolean  "premium",                default: false
    t.integer  "bufete_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.boolean  "owner",                  default: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

I believe my associations are correct, but I could be mistaken. My main problem is in the controller. When a user creates a firm, how do I assign this user to be the owner of this Firm? At the same time how do I add this user to the Firm.users collection?

Also, how would I go for adding future users to a specific firm's users collection?

**Important: A user can only create ONE Firm. At the same time, a user can only belong to ONE firm as well. If a user creates a firm, it will belong to THAT firm.**

Comment: What the trouble? What's code doesn't work? Show us your controller, please.

Comment: I have added the create action from the controller. The problem is, when I create a Firm, I cannot reference the user that created it from the firm object...

Comment: add please your `schema.rb` file, and bufete model too.

Comment: Added the schema.rb file

Comment: The `Firm` model it's same as `Bufete` ?

Comment: Yes. Some of the model names in the code are in Spanish.

Comment: For future question, make it as clear as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume Bufete is equal to Firm model, in the code below I'll use Bufete instead of Firm. You can check whether the user can create a new Bufete before creating the Bufete record.

```
def create
   @user = current_user
   if @user.can_create_bufete?
     @bufete = Bufete.create(bufete_params)

     # assign user to @bufete instead of @bufete.users.create()
     @user.bufete = @bufete  
     @user.owner = true

     # add your response_to block for @user.saved

   else

     # add your response_to block of not creating new Bufete

   end

end
```

Then you'll check whether the user can create a Bufete object or not in your User model.

```
def can_create_bufete?
  !owner && !bufete.present? # or any condition that meets your requirement
end
```

Comment: Really simple and elegant answer, thank you. What about when I want to add a different User to a Firm? For exanple, I want to create a link to a view where I can introduce another user's e-mail address and the controller action will add this user to the Firm's _users_ collection.

Comment: @Jaime I'll create a form that receives username/email via input, form submit url points to a new controller action, which will find the User object and the Firm object and then assign the Firm object to user which is similar to the code block shown in the answer, except that Bufete object is not created but found by passing the Bufete id to the controller.